# Numpy: 3D to 2D maxtrix reshape with flattened order along one axis

Tags: arrays, numpy, reshape

I'd like to read in very large binary files (GB+) from disk and do a reshape for further processing. The structure of the data is like that: there are F frames with each frame consisting of B blocks of the length N while N is a number. I read the data in with np.fromfile and get a 1D np.array. I want to reshape the data in a way that they are in shape (F*N,B), so that I can easily operate on blocks. 
I have an approach that does what I want - but it uses a for-loop and builds a new array (so not very efficient):

```
import numpy as np
F,B,N= 2,2,2
Data3D = np.arange(F*B*N).reshape(F,B,N)
Data2D = np.zeros(F*B*N).reshape(F*N,B)

for i in np.arange(B):
   Data2D[:,i] = Data3D[:,i,:].ravel()
```

I don't achieve the flattened order (np.ravel() keeps the order) with a direct reshape-transformation, but I guess there is an efficient/elementary numpy approach for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to transform an array of the shape `(F, B, N)` to an array of the shape `(F, N, B)`. This can easily achieved with the `transpose()` function of Numpy, which allows aribtrary index permutations. If you want to merge the first two dimension then together, you can apply an appropriate reshape:

```
import numpy as np
F,B,N= 2,2,2
Data3D = np.arange(F*B*N).reshape(F,B,N)
Data2D = np.transpose(Data3D, (0, 2, 1)).reshape(F * N, B)
```